# Battery problem in Activa I with in 3 months

Tags: battery, starting, scooter, activa

Within 3 months Activa I getting battery problem, if Activa not ride for 3 days it's ideal for 3 and more days it's not getting started without kick. It's irritating ,worst scooter . Previously I used TVs scooty that was for 10 years but never got this type issue.

Comment: Is this a new scooter, or a new battery or is this a new problem?  Please provide some details and history.

Comment: This is new scooter, purchased in September 2019